# Given an input, return the row which has a value of a range which contains that input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search, multi-index

I'm new, so please be gentle. I'm self-taught, so I may come across as a bit of an idiot.

So I have a Pandas Data Frame with multi-level indexing.

```
TEST     Gender     Age     Category     Level     Points     Curl Ups
IST      Female     20-24   Outstanding  High      100        105-500
                            Outstanding  Medium    95         103-104
                            Outstanding  Low       90         100-102
...       ...       ...         ...        ...      ...        ...
                    25-29   Outstanding  High      100        103-500
                            Outstanding  Medium    95         100-102
...
```

I want to be able to put in inputs for test, gender, age, and the number of curl-ups an individual did, i.e.; for the test IST, a female who was 26 years old and did 100 curl ups would look like

```
['IST','Female',26,100]
```

The output I'm looking for would be points, category-level. I.e.;

```
[95, 'Outstanding-Medium']
```

So it needs to be able to take an input of 26 for 'Age', and know to jump to the rows that fall under the 25-29 block, and then take the input of 100 and know to pull the row that 100 falls in, i.e.; 100-102. These are inclusive (100 up to and including 102 Curl Ups at age 26 gets you a score of 95 points, which is an outstanding medium).

I've attempted to use loc, but everything I've found does it another way, it asks for rows where you put in the range you want, and then the rows that contain values within that range are pulled.

What I need is, you give it a value, it pulls out the row that has a range that contains that value.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a fully fleshed-out answer, but I'm thinking this general idea could work for you. The idea is to create new columns in the dataframe that stand for the minimum and maximum of each range value. Then you can pretty simply filter the dataframe based on those values:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Curl Ups'] = ['100-500', '100-300', '200-300']
df['Age'] = ['20-24', '25-29', '30-34']
df['Points'] = [50, 60, 70]
df['Category'] = ['Decent', 'Average', 'Good']

# Create new min & max columns
df['min_curlups'] = [int(x[:x.index('-')]) for x in df['Curl Ups']]
df['max_curlups'] = [int(x[x.index('-')+1:]) for x in df['Curl Ups']]

df['min_age'] = [int(x[:x.index('-')]) for x in df['Age']]
df['max_age'] = [int(x[x.index('-')+1:]) for x in df['Age']]

# Filter by contestant's value being within the range
num_curlups = 200
filtered_df = df.loc[(df['min_curlups'] < num_curlups) & (num_curlups < df['max_curlups'])]
print(filtered_df[['Points', 'Category']])
```

---

### **EDIT**

I missed the multi-index part before. In fact, I'd never heard of that functionality in Pandas. Hooray for learning new things! 
Here's a solution that seems to work and hopefully doesn't need too much tweaking for your use:

First, setting up a test DataFrame and adding in the columns my method needs for filtering:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=[np.array(['IST', 'IST', 'IST', 'IST', 'ELSE', 'ELSE']),np.array(['Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male'])])
df.index.names = ['TEST', 'Gender']
df['Curl Ups'] = ['100-700', '100-300', '100-300', '100-300', '200-300', '400-500']
df['Age'] = ['20-24', '25-29', '30-34', '20-24', '30-34', '20-24']
df['Points'] = [90, 60, 70, 80, 70, 80]
df['Category'] = ['Outstanding', 'Average', 'Good', 'Better-than-me', 'Good', 'Better-than-me']
df['Level'] = ['Low', 'Medium', 'High', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High']

# Create 'Category-Level' combined column
df['Category-Level'] = df['Category'] + '-' + df['Level']

# Create new min & max columns
df['min_Curl Ups'] = [int(x[:x.index('-')]) for x in df['Curl Ups']]
df['max_Curl Ups'] = [int(x[x.index('-')+1:]) for x in df['Curl Ups']]

df['min_Age'] = [int(x[:x.index('-')]) for x in df['Age']]
df['max_Age'] = [int(x[x.index('-')+1:]) for x in df['Age']]

df
```

And here's a function that should take inputs similar to what you required and outputs the desired information:

```
def filter_multiindex_df( df, inputs, input_fields=['TEST', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Curl Ups'], outputs=['Points', 'Category-Level'] ):

    # Pull out the inputs corresponding to multi-level indices & filter to get the DF cross-section
    input_idx = [i for i,x in enumerate(input_fields) for j,y in enumerate(df.index.names) if x == y]
    index_inputs = [inputs[i] for i in input_idx]
    filt_df = df.xs(index_inputs)

    # Filter based on the rest of the inputs that weren't indices
    for i, field in enumerate(input_fields):
        if i not in input_idx:
            filt_df = filt_df.loc[ (filt_df['min_'+field] <= inputs[i]) & (inputs[i] <= filt_df['max_'+field])]

    return filt_df[outputs].values[0]


# Test the function    
print(filter_multiindex_df(df, inputs=['IST', 'Female', 22, 100]))
```

Comment: While this idea works for the curl-ups columns, it doesn't work out well when you've got multi-level indexing. Do you know how we could do it using df.xs or something to that effect?

Comment: While it's not pretty, see my edited attempt above.